# Java InputMismatchException is thrown for certain input in my program idk why its being thrown

Tags: java, inputmismatchexception

Code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class InputInJava {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


        String name = sc.next();

        String fName = sc.nextLine();

        int number =  sc.nextInt();

        float Fnumber = sc.nextFloat();

        double Dnumber = sc.nextDouble();

        short Snumber = sc.nextShort();

        byte Bnumber = sc.nextByte();

        long Lnumber = sc.nextLong();


        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(fName);
        System.out.println(number);
        System.out.println(Fnumber);
        System.out.println(Dnumber);
        System.out.println(Snumber);
        System.out.println(Bnumber);
        System.out.println(Lnumber);


    }
}
```

Input:

```
String String 1 1
1
```

i checked on overflow and a few other sites which poped up on google i tried different input such as
Input2:

```
String String 1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Output is:

```
String
 String 1
1
1.0
1.0
1
1
1
```

So why is it reading the input for nextLine upto 1 spaces only and then it reads next input?

Comment: `#nextLine` will read up to the newline character (including spaces and numbers). `#next` will read up to a delimiter (which excludes whitespace from being read). Your current code necessitates that the six expected numbers come _after_ the newline.

Comment: For future reference, questions of this type should include a copy of the [stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors). It also helps if the question indicates which line in your source code caused the exception to be thrown.  Use text copy-and-paste to ensure accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're facing is related to how the Scanner class in Java works. When you use `sc.next()`, it reads only one token (a sequence of characters separated by whitespace) from the input. On the other hand, when you use `sc.nextLine()`, it reads the entire line including any spaces until the end of the line.

In your example, when you input "String String 1 1 1", the sc.next() reads "String", and then sc.nextLine() reads the rest of the line, which is " String 1 1 1". This is why you see unexpected behavior when trying to read the next input.

One way to do that would be like so :

```
String name = sc.next();
// Consume the newline character left in the buffer
sc.nextLine();
```